# Android: How to get background color of Activity in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How can I get background color and text color (default for child views) of an Activity in Java?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
TypedArray array = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {  
    android.R.attr.colorBackground, 
    android.R.attr.textColorPrimary, 
}); 
int backgroundColor = array.getColor(0, 0xFF00FF); 
int textColor = array.getColor(1, 0xFF00FF); 
array.recycle();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

For Background

```
TypedArray array = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {
        android.R.attr.windowBackground});
    int backgroundColor = array.getColor(0, 0xFF00FF);
    array.recycle();
    view.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
```