# How to GET Layout's background color?

Tags: java, android

How to GET Layout's background color ?

For example i have a `MainActivity` and `FormOne.xml` and `FormTwo.xml` as layout. Now i want to GET background color of **FormTwo.xml** in MainActivity...

Is it possible? and how

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As you can find th answer in another question ([Android: How to get background color of Activity in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656586/android-how-to-get-background-color-of-activity-in-java)).

```
TypedArray array = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {  
    android.R.attr.colorBackground, 
    android.R.attr.textColorPrimary, 
}); 
int backgroundColor = array.getColor(0, 0xFF00FF); 
int textColor = array.getColor(1, 0xFF00FF); 
array.recycle();
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about getting background's color of a ANOTHER activity/layout? Ex. FORM2.xml ?

Comment: Just a guess, but it can work:
A bit hax, but maybe you can inflate the layout and then get the background of the activity. Later you can override the inflated view. I cannot try it atm, I don't have working adt on my pc, and have several other things to do. 
If it isn't working, I'm sorry, but i dont have anything else in my mind.